# gdb full file not being loaded

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, gdb

I used Visual Studio 2013 to compile and debug a C program. Then compiled the same program in gcc and tried debugging but for some reason, I am not able to **jump** to a specific line. The message I get is no line *line_number* in current file.

Here is the C Code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    while (1) { 
    }
    printf("Hello World!");
    printf("Bye World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Now for the above code in VS 2013, I am able to move the yellow arrow and make it point to the print function, but in case of GDB I am not able to use **jump** to move to the print function.

I used **gcc -g file.c -o file** to compile my C file. My guess is since its an infinite loop, some optimization only shows instruction till the loop.

Edit:

GDB commands I used are

1) gdb
2) file exec_name
3) break line_number
4) run
5) jump line_number

If I modify the loop to

```
int x = 1;
while (x) {
}
```

The **jump** works fine

Comment: How exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: GCC could optimize out these lines.

Comment: @Shawn I didn't get you? are you asking how I am using gdb

Comment: @ks1322 any way to not do that? if i change the loop to int x = 1; while (x) {} I am able to jump to print function

Comment: Yes. What commands are you using?

Comment: gdb>file exec_name>break line_number>run>jump line_number

Comment: @AAB Why are you exactly need to program like this? Why not building the source code in a way that it fits your needs in a more "common" way? What is your aim exactly?

Comment: @RobertS I am trying to debug a process that makes use of a .so/.dll this way. I don't have code for the .exe but do have code for the .dll/.so. Just need to see the data and functions called in our .dll/.so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in case of GDB I am not able to use jump to move to the print function

This is because GCC does not emit unreachable code even with optimizations disabled with `-O0`. See it on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/lpXNmn. You can jump in Visual Studio because the code is emitted: https://godbolt.org/z/7452oP. It seems that there is no way to force GCC to emit this unreachable code as well. And actually there is no sense to emit it for this artificial example.